# DevOps Pipeline VSBuild task fails to find nuget packages

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, devops

I have a DevOps Pipeline for a C# Web API that doesn't find the nuget packages after the nuget restore is completed and the vsbuild command is run.

Below is the YAML file:

```
trigger:
- dev

pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'

variables:
  solution: 'WebAPI/myWebAPI/*.sln'
  buildPlatform: 'Any CPU'
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'

steps:
- task: NuGetToolInstaller@1

- task: NuGetCommand@2
  inputs:
    command: 'restore'
    restoreSolution: '$(solution)'
    feedsToUse: 'config'
    nugetConfigPath: 'WebAPI/myWebAPI/myWebAPI/nuget.config'
    restoreDirectory: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/WebAPI/myWebAPI/packages'

- task: CmdLine@2
  inputs:
    script: 'ls -Rla'

- task: VSBuild@1
  inputs:
    solution: '$(solution)'
    platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
    msbuildArgs: '/p:ReferencePath="$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/WebAPI/myWebAPI/packages" /p:RestorePackagesConfig=true /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:PackageLocation="$(build.artifactStagingDirectory)"'
    configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'
```

When I run this YAML in DevOps, the VSBuild task fails not able to find nuget packages with logging that looks like this...

```
"D:\a\_tasks\VSBuild_71a9a2d3-a98a-4caa-96ab-affca411ecda\1.199.0\ps_modules\MSBuildHelpers\vswhere.exe" -version [17.0,18.0) -latest -format json
"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\MSBuild\Current\Bin\msbuild.exe" "D:\a\1\s\WebAPI\myWebAPI\myWebAPI.sln" /nologo /nr:false /dl:CentralLogger,"D:\a\_tasks\VSBuild_71a9a2d3-a98a-4caa-96ab-affca411ecda\1.199.0\ps_modules\MSBuildHelpers\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.MSBuild.Logger.dll";"RootDetailId=7bbf82be-4773-4dce-8327-de23d86dafd6|SolutionDir=D:\a\1\s\WebAPI\myWebAPI|enableOrphanedProjectsLogs=true"*ForwardingLogger,"D:\a\_tasks\VSBuild_71a9a2d3-a98a-4caa-96ab-affca411ecda\1.199.0\ps_modules\MSBuildHelpers\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.MSBuild.Logger.dll"  /p:platform="Any CPU" /p:configuration="Release" /p:VisualStudioVersion="17.0" /p:_MSDeployUserAgent="VSTS_704c3632-77a5-4025-9f8d-47b795f1f578_build_41_0"
Building the projects in this solution one at a time. To enable parallel build, please add the "-m" switch.
Build started 6/27/2022 10:57:43 PM.
Project "D:\a\1\s\WebAPI\myWebAPI\myWebAPI.sln" on node 1 (default targets).
ValidateSolutionConfiguration:
  Building solution configuration "Release|Any CPU".
Project "D:\a\1\s\WebAPI\myWebAPI\myWebAPI.sln" (1) is building "D:\a\1\s\WebAPI\myWebAPI\myWebAPI\myWebAPI.csproj" (2) on node 1 (default targets).
PrepareForBuild:
  Creating directory "bin\".
  Creating directory "obj\Release\".
ResolveAssemblyReferences:
  Primary reference "DevExpress.Web.ASPxThemes.v21.1, Version=21.1.6.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a, processorArchitecture=MSIL".
##[warning]C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\MSBuild\Current\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2302,5): Warning MSB3245: Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate the assembly "DevExpress.Web.ASPxThemes.v21.1, Version=21.1.6.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a, processorArchitecture=MSIL". Check to make sure the assembly exists on disk. If this reference is required by your code, you may get compilation errors.
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\MSBuild\Current\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2302,5): warning MSB3245: Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate the assembly "DevExpress.Web.ASPxThemes.v21.1, Version=21.1.6.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a, processorArchitecture=MSIL". Check to make sure the assembly exists on disk. If this reference is required by your code, you may get compilation errors. [D:\a\1\s\WebAPI\myWebAPI\myWebAPI\myWebAPI.csproj]
          For SearchPath "{TargetFrameworkDirectory}".
          Considered "C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.8\DevExpress.Web.ASPxThemes.v21.1.winmd", but it didn't exist.
          Considered "C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.8\DevExpress.Web.ASPxThemes.v21.1.dll", but it didn't exist.
          Considered "C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.8\DevExpress.Web.ASPxThemes.v21.1.exe", but it didn't exist.
```

The VSBuild task fails because it isn't finding the nuget packages, so the namespaces aren't there during the build.  It happens for all the packages in the project.  I added a task to list the directory contents and the directory structure is the same as when I build the Visual Studio project locally.  It builds fine locally too.

Can anyone help?  Any ideas on what else I can do?

Answer (score 0):

The issue ended up being that I had to update DevExpress to version 21.2.6 and then manually add the 2 lines below to the packages.config file.  Then the DevOps Pipeline worked.

```
  <package id="DevExpress.Web.Mvc5" version="21.2.6" targetFramework="net48" />
  <package id="DevExpress.Web.Mvc5.Dashboard" version="21.2.6" targetFramework="net48" />
```